# Rails assets precompiling failure due to bad JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ecmascript-6

Been having this problem for the last couple of days. When trying to push to Heroku (or trying to precompile assets in general) I receive this error:

```
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (>)
remote:        JS_Parse_Error.get ((execjs):3538:621)
remote:        (execjs):4060:48
remote:        (execjs):1:102
remote:        Object.<anonymous> ((execjs):1:120)
remote:        Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
remote:        Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
remote:        Module.load (module.js:565:32)
remote:        tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
remote:        Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
remote:        Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
```

I've scoured the js files in my assets folder for the bad operator(>), but cannot find it. I've tried pretty much everything involving Uglifier, and still no dice.

Comment: If you’re still using the old assets pipeline and you have es2015 js, it won’t be transpiled automatically and give you the error. On which version of rails are you?

Comment: 5.1.4, I just resolved the issue by iterating over the files